# Netsuite PHP unable to add items to new Sales Order

Tags: php, netsuite, suitetalk

as the title says, I am having no luck adding item(s) to a Sales Order when using the NetSuite PHP API Client created by Ryan Winchester (https://github.com/netsuitephp/netsuite-php).  It's really just the Netsuite PHPToolKit with namespaces and autoloading, so it works the same.  When I get to the items for the SO, I loop thru them as such:

```
$items = array();
foreach ($order->basketDetails->basketItems as $item) {
    $cartItem = new SalesOrderItem();
    $cartItem->item = $itemResponse->searchResult->recordList->record[0]->internalId;
    $cartItem->quantity = $item->productQuantity;
    $cartItem->rate = "42.97";
    $items[] = $cartItem;
```

Once I have all the items in the array, I add them to a SalesOrderItemList:

```
$itemList = new SalesOrderItemList();
$itemList->item = $items;
```

Then I add the item list to the Sales Order ($sale is created earlier in the script with: $sale = new SalesOrder();)

```
$sale->itemList->item = $itemList;
```

However, when I try to execute the creation of the Sales Order, I get this error:

> [04-Apr-2023 15:11:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server.userException] org.xml.sax.SAXException: item on {urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com}SalesOrderItemList must be of type {urn:sales_2021_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com}SalesOrderItem in /var/www/composer/vendor/ryanwinchester/netsuite-php/src/NetSuiteClient.php:196

I'm not sure where to go from here as each item is its own SalesOrderItem object.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

please try changing this:

```
$sale->itemList->item = $itemList;
```

to this:

```
$sale->itemList = $itemList;
```

Comment: Thank you for this @jrebs  Doing thing and realizing that $cartItem->item was supposed to be a RecordRef and not the internal ID alone, I was able to get this working.